# Regex to search and replace array keys

Tags: php, regex

i need a regex to search this:
$var[prod_menu]

and replace with this:
$var['prod_menu']

At the moment my regex make this:
$var['rod_men']

My regex:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\'](.*)[^\']\]/U', '['$1']', $input_lines);
```

Where is the error?

Comment: There is no code here that adds `_` before `var`. What code have you really got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the capturing group after the opening `[` and close before the `]`

Note that this part in your pattern `[^\'](.*)[^\']` uses 2 times a negated character class which actually expects a minimum of 2 characters.

Another way to write your pattern could be using a negated character class matching not `[`, `]`, `$` or a `'`

```
\[([^]\[$']+)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7Ttjt/1)

In the replacement use

```
['$1']
```

Or make the match more restrictive matching 1+ word characters.

```
\[(\w+)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TL4QyL/1)

Comment: Yes that work but there is another litle problem. It always replaces this $var[$test] to $var['$test']

Comment: @MarkusHH What is the expected outcome? You could also match 1+ word chars to make the match more specific `\[(\w+)\]` See https://regex101.com/r/TL4QyL/1

Comment: $var[$test] should stay $var[$test], only replace if string in brackets

Comment: @MarkusHH Or exclude the dollar sign from the match `\[([^]\[$']+)\]` See https://regex101.com/r/n7Ttjt/1

Comment: \[(\w+)\] That's it!! Thank your very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your capture group to include the extra chars at the start and end...

```
preg_replace('/\[([^\'].*[^\'])\]/U', "['$1']", $input_lines);
```

(I've also fixed the problem with quotes in `'['$1']'`).

Comment: This will not work if the keys is less than 3 character long (i.e. `array[i]`)